# Firefox is sending Malformed Requests

Tags: 13.04, firefox, browser

Its weeks now I'm experience same 400 error. I had never had it before. I tried safe mode with no extensions but nope, I get same error. I don't know what to do anymore. Searched web as well as AU with no success.

I need any advice to get me fine. Switching to Chromium/Chrome is not an option for me as have been for many years (since early life of FF) and so I'm not only used to it but loves it.

Here is my system

- **Ubuntu 13.04**
- **Unity 7.0.0**
- **Firefox 21.0**

Comment: Could you provide some context for when you see the error?

Comment: It happens random and I have to refresh the page sometimes up to 10 times to get to the page. Not sure if that answers the "context"

Comment: In other words, what are you (or Firefox) doing when the error appears? What does the error look like? Is it a pop-up? Can you continue browsing? What is the specific error number? What is the exact wording?

Comment: Error is http Error 400. Various sites have custom messages but it actually means that request sent by browser(cum FF) is not understood by server. It happens much of times I try to access LinkedIn or jamiiforums.com

Comment: Here is a sample of what just happened `400 Bad Request `

Comment: Do you access the Internet via a proxy server? If so, it might be  affecting your requests. Whilst you might not want to switch browsers, using a different one for a while might help you identify whether the problem is with Firefox or not.

Comment: Came across http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html and it offers a few troubleshooting tips.

Comment: @DavidEdwards, I checked it was set to system Proxy so I changed to no proxy but still same error. Same pages can be accessed by Chromium just fine so I think it is FF!

Comment: @vasa1, thanks for the link, let me try it out!

Comment: "*I tried safe mode with no extensions*" but a more thorough way may be to make another profile altogether: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles

Comment: Ok Let me make a profile. Before that can I import passowrds and bookmarks into the new profile? I don't want to loose all that I have collected over years!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the silver bullet but have solved 99% of the problems and I'm comfortable with few that remains. The Answer was to reset Firefox. Go to menu with path shown below and click "reset firefox" button and you are done

```
Help >> Troubleshoot Information
```